# JavaScript variable life time

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am learning node.js and JavaScript. Following is the code. I found the var `http` is outside the function `start2`. I am wondering why it works? Since we only exports function `start2`, right?

Is this some concept about closure? (I've tried put the var `http` inside the `start2`. It works for sure.)

```
var http = require('http');

function start2(){
    function onRequest(request,response){
        console.log("Request recieved");
        response.writeHead(200,{"Content-Type":"text/html"});
        response.write("<h1>Hello world</h1>");
        response.end(); 
    }
    http.createServer(onRequest).listen(8888);
    console.log("Server has started.");
}
exports.start=start2;
```

Comment: yes you explained it :) but nothing to do with the title life time

Comment: This is a classical example of a closure.A closure is a special kind of object that combines two things: a function, and the environment in which that function was created. The environment consists of any local variables that were in-scope at the time that the closure was created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could put `var http = require('http');` inside your function but most often that's not how people code it. People place it at the top like you have it. Why? This is a call to the module system to load module `http`. Most often, you want to do this *once* and make it available for your entire file. If you are doing to use this module multiple times in your file you don't want to call `require` again and again.

If a module it is rarely used and perhaps expensive to load, then it may make sense to have the `require` call inside a function, instead of paying the cost of loading it each and every time:

```
function calledUnderExceptionalCircumstances() {
    var expensive = require('expensive');
    expensive.foo();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the code that you have attached, require loads a module into the global scope. Since you have defined function start2 in the same scope, due to closure, var http is available inside function start2.

In the second code snippet you have provided, due to closure, the reference to the variable env_var1 is made available inside f1,  which is getting re - assigned.

If at all, instead of directly re - assigning env_var1 if you are redefining env_var1 as var env_var1, var env_var1 becomes a local variable and it's scope is confined within f1 and inside f2, it would print "aaa" instead of "bbb" as you would have expected.

Hope this helps.